# .htaccess on localhost - Redirect to 404 page but KEEP wrong url?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, localhost

So I'm new to .htaccess and I can't get it to work properly.
This is my file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/404.php
```

It goes to the "404 page". But how can I keep the wrong domain while it still redirects to the page? Ex. if a typed "http://localhost/soup/yummi.php" - It should still display that url?

Comment: Reading the documentation helps. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument: _“Note that when you specify an ErrorDocument that points to a remote URL (ie. anything with a method such as http in front of it), Apache will send a redirect to the client to tell it where to find the document, even if the document ends up being on the same server. This has several implications, the most important being that the client will not receive the original error status code, but instead will receive a redirect status code.”_ - so, don’t use an absolute URL, but a local/relative one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subfolder/403.php [L]
```

Solved it for me :)

Answer (score -2):

Try this one out please

```
ErrorDocument 404 /soup/404.php
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19217570)

Comment: This doesn't apply here, @markwalker_ :) The problem is different here but I don't think it fits any of the options in the popup.

Comment: @Al.G. Yeah it's one of those that doesn't fit the options but I think still needs something because it's not really an answer. Looking again thought, it really just needs editing to fix.